# Is "Pegasus" in iPad crash report data something to be concerned about?

Tags: ipad, malware

Recently getting interested in how Apple products and apps use, store, and disseminate my info.  Came across Argo.ips (which appears to be related to netflix app) in Data and Diagnostics and decided to look further into when I noticed its binary image referencing call history, messages, cloudphoto library, and other info that didn't seem relevant.  I do not see these references made in crash reports for other apps.

Noticed the following listed in binary image and could not find a clear explanation online.

`0x18f2b8000-0x18f2eafff Pegasus arm64 <16f175f3c4b5343fbba9f33a019df587> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Pegasus.framework/Pegasus`

Should this be concerning?  Is this Spyware, or just something with the same name as other nefarious programs? Is there a reason the Netflix app crash report would  reference these other areas of my iPad?   My next step, when time allows is to pull the rest of the logs and see what actual commands are occurring.

Comment: Are you looking at a crash and seeing system libraries linked? It’s not clear how you are determining access to specific data...

Comment: I'm looking in Diagnostics & Usage under the Privacy tab

Comment: It is isn't listed as Jetsam event, but yes this is a crash report for the Argo.ips

Comment: Sorry if my terminology is off, this is something that I am just beginning to educate myself on.  I suppose it could be reference and not access.  I am asking because I am interested.  With a quick google of Pegasus, how could you not be, lol